# Why windows7 cannot access resource on network by IP address?

Tags: windows, authentication, networking, dns

i am using windows 7 until yesterday  it was ok when I put **\\192.168.1.1** in explorer it opens the shared resources but in these 2 days it ask username and password however i use network administrator and password. it did not open and asking again for username and password but when i use hostname or computer name e.g **\\dc-aqua** or ** \\mailserver**

it opens shared folders printers.

one more thing even i use **\\mailserver\d$** permanently asking for username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an expert system administrator guided to change

control panel -> administrative tools -> local security policy -> local policies -> security options ->  Network security: LAN Manager authentication level >set to  **Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated**

this was solved my problem